# RegEx match of a string

Tags: c#, regex

Im working and a fun project with c# and now I have a problem with my **RegEx**.  I have tried some varitations but didnt found a solution for this. I want a **RegEx** for this string `"##Test1##"`.

So I have tried this RegEx here:

```
[\#]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[\#]{2}
```

And its working fine but my problem is that,
When passed `"###Test1###"` the RegEx ignores the first and last `#` and matches on the inner `"##Test1##"`.

But I dont want that.

The **RegEx** only should match to this string `##Test1##`.

Hopefully here are some guys who can help me with that problem.
Greetings,

Comment: If you want a regex for **that** string, it would be `"^##Test1##$"`. Can you tell us which bits will vary if you need to support different strings? ie. give us some examples?

Comment: I think the main point is that you need to apply `anchors` to ensure the string consists of only that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the regular expression should **only** match the string you've specified, here's your regular expression:

```
^##Test1##$
```

If you want it to match a string like `"##(any digit or letter here)##"`, then this will work:

```
^##[a-zA-Z0-9]+##$
```

This will match strings like

```
##abc##
##123##
```

but not

```
###xxx###     <-- 3 #'s
```

---

I think the main part you're looking for here are these two symbols:

```
+------------------- matches the beginning of the string
|                +-- matches the end of the string
v                v
^##[a-zA-Z0-9]+##$
```

These two will make sure you're not searching to the string to see if your pattern exists *inside* it, but you're instead checking if the string matches the pattern completely.

Comment: Ah thanks, ^ define the start of the match and $ the end, or? Thanks for that answer it works nice :)

Answer (score 0):

This will match the required string when standing alone, and also if it is embedded in a longer character sequence:

```
[^#]*##[a-zA-Z0-9]+##[^#]*

Hello##World##! -> matches=true
##World##       -> matches=true

Hello##World### -> matches=false
###World###     -> matches=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, thats because is contained inside, so is obviously right. What about with "excluding" characters like at the end/beginning `.^#*` but obviosly that only works if you want to avoid just that character...